# Android widget vanishes from emulator on remoteviews update

Tags: php, mysql, android, widget, blob

My MySQL DB table holds a BLOB image with image_id as key. I am trying to do the following.

1.HttpPost("http://example.com/RetrieveImage.php") from Android App with the image_id in name value pairs.

The PHP Script is as follows:

```
<?php
mysql_connect("host","userid","password");
mysql_select_db("database");
$q=mysql_query("SELECT image FROM testblob WHERE image_id =".$_REQUEST['image_id']."");
$e=mysql_fetch_assoc($q);
print($e);
mysql_close();
?>
```

2. ```
   httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
   InputStream is = entity.getContent(); 
   response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
   HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
   is = entity.getContent();
   ```
3. Store the BLOB data in Inputstream object is to byte array

   ```
   ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
           byte[] buf = new byte[10240];
           int n = 0;
           try {
               while ((n=is.read(buf))>=0)
               {
               baos.write(buf, 0, n);
               }
   is.close();
   byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();
   ```
4. Convert the byte array to bitmap and set ImageView of the Android widget to the Image

   ```
   Bitmap bitmap;
   RemoteViews updateViews = null;
   bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
   updateViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.tuwidget);
   updateViews.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.tuwidget_img_btn, bitmap);
   return updateViews;
   ```

Once this is run, I dont know why the widget does not even show up on the emulator and 
cannot even add the widget anymore to the screen. What am I doing wrong? Any help is much appreciated.

Oh and here is my widget layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AbsoluteLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/tuwidget"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/tuwidget_img_btn"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>
</ImageView>
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

Comment: Try using some other layout instead of AbsoluteLayout. Its deprecated and it requires absolute locations of its children. Try LinearLayout.

Comment: Tried Linear Layout still does not work....But I found the problem still need some help solving this issue.

Comment: The BLOB from the MySQL DB is retrieved and is received by byte array bytes.This is what most likely does not work bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length); I thought this would convert the bytes array into a bitmap image that was saved as a BLOB but always returns null and that was why the widget was GONE. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the problem - Bitmap was returning Null so the widget initial layout vanished. Issue was in the php.

Answer (score 0):

Now it works!!! on browser and app

new php:

```
<?php
mysql_connect("host","login","password");
mysql_select_db("dbname");
$q=mysql_query("SELECT picture FROM tablename WHERE id>='".$_REQUEST['id']."'");

$e=mysql_fetch_row($q);
header('Content-Length: '.strlen($e[0]));
header('Content-type: image/jpg');
echo $e[0];
mysql_close();?>
```